# Hermite polynomial relations

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, hermite-polynomials

How one can prove the relation on Hermite polynomial given as $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty H_n\left(x+\frac{x_0}{2}\right)e^{^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}}dx=\sqrt{\pi}x_0^n$$I also didn't understand the meaning of $\displaystyle H_n\left(x+\frac{x_0}{2}\right)$, what does that signify, I know by the way that $H_n(x)$ represents the Hermite polynomial but what is the meaning of $\displaystyle H_n\left(x+\frac{x_0}{2}\right)$? Please explain this alongwith.

**Thanks**.

Comment: $x_0$ is just some constant. Let $x_0/2$ be some constant $b$ and write $H_n(x+b)$.

Comment: Also I believe that should be $\sqrt{2\pi}{x_0}^n$ because 
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty H_1(x+1/2)\exp(-x^2/2)\mathrm{d}x\approx 2.50663$$
Which looks a lot like $\sqrt{2\pi}$.

Comment: This might be because people often use subtly different definitions of $H_n$.

Comment: Your weighting function $\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)$ define the Hermite polynomials you are using.  In your case, you need to use the Statistician's multiplied by $\sqrt{2\pi}$.  See my proof below, your integral is not quite right.  @K.defaoite seems like you used the physicists here, the integral $$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty H_1(x+1/2)\exp(-x^2/2)dx\approx 1.25331413731550$$, which looks a lot like $\sqrt{\pi/2}$.

Answer (score 2):

This convolution integral is proven in Theorem 2.7 in a recent preprint "A General Expression for Hermite Expansions with Applications" found here: http://dx.doi.org/10.13140/RG.2.2.30843.44325

Define the integral you are looking for
$$
I_n = \int_{-\infty}^\infty H_n\left(x+\frac{x_0}{2}\right)\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)dx
$$

In order to prove this, we Taylor expand the Hermite polynomial in $x_0$
$$
I_n= \sum_{m=0}^n {n \choose m} \left(\frac{x_0}{2}\right)^m\int_{-\infty}^\infty H_{n-m}(x)\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)dx.
$$
This integral is only zero for $n=m$ by the orthogonality of Hermite polynomials
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty H_\alpha(x)H_\beta(x)\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)dx=c_n \delta_{\alpha\beta}
$$
where $c_n$ depends on your weighting function and normalization.  Here it is $c_n = \sqrt{2\pi}n!$.

Plugging this into the sum results in
$$
I_n=\left(\frac{x_0}{2}\right)^n\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)dx
$$
leading to (almost) your result
$$
I_n = \sqrt{2\pi}\left(\frac{x_0}{2}\right)^n.
$$